# ETH Mining with PhoenixMiner - New install 18.04.5 OpenCL driver but "no available GPUs for mining" error

Tags: drivers, graphics

New Install of Ubuntu 18.04.5
Installed amdgpu driver `./amdgpu-install --opencl=pal,legacy -y --headless`

Getting an error from PhoenixMiner saying there are "No available GPUs"

What am I doing wrong?

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 731f (rev c1)
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 731f (rev c1)
0f:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 731f (rev c1)
12:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 731f (rev c1)
15:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 731f (rev c1)
18:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 731f (rev c1)

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Phoenix Miner 5.5c Linux/gcc - Release build
--------------------------------------------

No CUDA driver found
OpenCL driver version: 20.40-1147287
No avaiable GPUs for mining. Please check your drivers and/or hardware.
```

UPDATE:
I see now that after trying the amdgpu-pro installer there is a warning WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel
More info:

`/opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/clinfo Number of platforms:               1   Platform Profile:               FULL_PROFILE   Platform Version:                OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3180.7)   Platform Name:                AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing   Platform Vendor:              Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.   Platform Extensions:                 cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices      Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing Number of devices:              0`

I see someone mentioned in another tread going to kernel 5.4 so I'm doing that now and will see if that resolves it

UPDATE: 14:45 CDT
System would not boot after upgrading kernel - going to try to find an ISO w/ kernel updated for fresh install